# How to findAll in mongoosejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My code is like that:

```
SiteModel.find(
    {},
    function(docs) {
        next(null, { data: docs });
    }
);
```

but it never returns anything... but if I specify something in the {}  then there is one record.  so, how to findall?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this code to debug:

```js
SiteModel.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (!err) { 
        console.log(docs);
        process.exit();
    }
    else {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Comment: Any ideas why this wouldn't work when I run this from the terminal like `node filename.js`?

Comment: Note you don't even need the empty curly braces if you are using a `then-catch` like paradigm.

Answer (score 24):

The 2017 Node 8.5 way

```
try {
  const results = await SiteModel.find({});
  console.log(results);
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find):

```
let result = SiteModel.find({}, function (err, docs) {});
```

or using async await you can do like this also:

```
let result = await SiteModel.find({});
```

Answer (score 2):

`const result = await SiteModel.find()` - Without the `{}` in the `.find()` function works as well.

Answer (score 0):

exports.getAllUsers = (req, res) => { userSchema .find() .then((data) => res.status(200).json({ status: "success", results: data.length, data: { data, }, }) ) .catch((err) => res.status(404).json({ status: "error", message: "Not records found", }) ); };

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).