# How to get data from all objects using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express

So I would like to get all users's jobs from `users` collection while now I can only get the logged user's jobs.

Here is my user schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String},
  password: { type: String },
  jobs: [{
    title: { type: String },
    description: { type: String }
  }]
});
```

And this is my middleware

```
// Get user's jobs
exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ jobs: req.user.jobs });
}
```

As an example I am user with id (1) but we are three users. How can I get `jobs` from other users?

I am new in this backend side and I will really appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to findAll in mongoosejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247541/how-to-findall-in-mongoosejs)

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks buddy very helpful